Baby Rudin p211
In this example, How do I go to Inequality (6) from the Inequality above? Can you derive this part?


Do you know the definition of $|A|$?

Just divide by $|x|^2$ then take the square root of. both sides, then apply the definition of $|A|.$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}^2 \, \cdot  \sum_{j=1}^{n}c_{j}^2=(a_{i1}^2+a_{i2}^2+\dots+a_{in}^2)(c_1^2+c_2^2+\dots+c_n^2)
\\ = (a_{i1}c_1)^2+(a_{i2}c_2)^2+\dots +(a_{in}c_{n})^2+\text{some non-negative terms}\\
=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_{ij}c_j)^2+\text{some non-negative terms}
\\ \geq \sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_{ij}c_j)^2$$
